# Review needed: ConcurrentmodificationException while ReentrantLock ensures that this is not possible

Tags: java, thread-safety, concurrentmodification

Context: [Github: issue 20](https://github.com/TerminatorNL/Tiquality/issues/20) and [Github: issue 22](https://github.com/TerminatorNL/Tiquality/issues/22)

I have a ConcurrentModificationException, but I do not know where to look. The variable is private, and only accessed within the same class where all access to it is locked using a ReentrantLock.

While in the loop, the objects do not get removed (So why does this exception occur?)

This is a broken down bit of code:

```java
private static final TreeMap<Long, TrackerHolder> TRACKER_LIST = new TreeMap<>();
private static final ReentrantLock TRACKER_LIST_LOCK = new ReentrantLock();

public static void tickUntil(long time){
    TRACKER_LIST_LOCK.lock();
    boolean hasWork = true;
    while(System.nanoTime() < time && hasWork) {
        hasWork = false;
        for(TrackerHolder holder : TRACKER_LIST.values()){ //This line is giving the error, indicating TRACKER_LIST is being modified somehow.
            Tracker tracker = holder.getTracker();
            if(tracker.needsTick()){
                hasWork = true;
                tracker.grantTick();
            }
        }
    }
    TRACKER_LIST_LOCK.unlock();
}
```

This is an open source project, which you can access [here](https://github.com/TerminatorNL/Tiquality/blob/220450a80c5afa37ebf6ab2005ea2ce1281c1290/src/main/java/cf/terminator/tiquality/tracking/TrackerManager.java#L69) (Linked to current point in time.)

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(TreeMap.java:1211) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.TreeMap$ValueIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1256) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at cf.terminator.tiquality.tracking.TrackerManager.tickUntil(TrackerManager.java:69) ~[TrackerManager.class:?]
    at cf.terminator.tiquality.monitor.TickMaster.onServerTick(TickMaster.java:64) ~[TickMaster.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.ASMEventHandler_2625_TickMaster_onServerTick_ServerTickEvent.invoke(.dynamic) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.ASMEventHandler.invoke(ASMEventHandler.java:90) ~[ASMEventHandler.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:746) ~[EventBus.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:696) ~[EventBus.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLCommonHandler.onPostServerTick(FMLCommonHandler.java:266) ~[FMLCommonHandler.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71217_p(MinecraftServer.java:712) ~[MinecraftServer.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:526) [MinecraftServer.class:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191]
```

I am at the point where I need someone else to look over this. I also would like to understand where this ConcurrentModificationException comes from, and how to prevent it in the future. I consider myself to be capable of writing pretty advanced code, but I might be missing something here.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Reading the code, I am wondering, is it posible that a call to grantTick actually changes the collection of trackers?

Comment: Given the lock is reentrant, so it can be "reacquired" in the same thread: is there any opportunity that "tracker.needsTick()" or "tracker.grantTick()" causes a call back into the TrackerManager... Which is mutating the state of the map?

Comment: In the meantime a quick fix (though performance hotspot) could be to copy the structure before you loop over it.

Comment: I checked that grantTick() and needsTick() does not alter the collection in any way.

Comment: Be aware your code may never unlock if it throws an exception. `unlock` should be in a `finally` block.